# C# - insert values from file into two arrays

Tags: c#

I want to read values from text file and insert them to 2 arrays, the first column to one array and the second column to another array.

For example:

```
Text file:  

0x223    0x2342342

0x21323  0x983298

0x908938 0x8382AA


arr1 :  0x223, 0x21323 , 0x908938

arr2 :  0x2342342,0x983298,0x8382AA
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try the split method of the string class for starters ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("sample.txt");
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    list1.Add(values[0]);
    list2.Add(values[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Text = File.ReadAllLines("Path");
foreach (var i in Text) {
   var SplitText = i.Split().Where(x=> x.Lenght>1).ToList();
   //@Array1 add SplitText[0]
   //@Array2 add SpliteText[1]

 }
```